# Trying to use qsort to sort a cstring

Tags: c++, parameters, constants, cstring, qsort

I am trying to sort two cstrings, and I'm running into trouble while using qsort to complete this task. I believe my problems are that I'm not sure what to put as the parameters for compare, if my compare function is correct, or if it is even necessary for me to write my own compare function at all.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


bool anagram(const char *s1, const char *s2);

int main() {
    string sWord1, sWord2;  
    char cWord1[10], cWord2[10];
    char *cPtr1 = cWord1;
    char *cPtr2 = cWord2;

    cout << "Enter Word 1: ";
    cin.getline(cWord1, 10);

    cout <<"\nEnter Word 2: ";
    cin.getline(cWord2, 10);

    anagram(cPtr1, cPtr2);

    return 0;
}

bool anagram(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    char w1[10];
    char w2[10];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        w1[i] = s1[i];
        w2[i] = s2[i];  
    }

    sort(w1.begin(), w1.end());  //DOES NOT WORK
    sort(begin(w1), end(w1)); //DOES NOT WORK - Says begin is not in std 
}
```

Comment: This is C++. Is `std::sort` not satisfactory?

Comment: These are arrays of `char`s, not C strings. You didn't guarantee the terminating `\0`.

Comment: @T.C.: Doesn't look like he needs to, since there's a length argument.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No he doesn't need to, but then it's a misnomer to call them C strings.

Comment: @Chris
I tried std::sort, but I'm receiving errors
[Error] request for member 'begin' in 'w1', which is of non-class type 'char [10]'

Comment: @Victor, I suggest using `std::string`, but both pointers and `std::begin` and `std::end` work for arrays.

Comment: @Chris we have to use chars for the assignment. I had to do a similar function that manipulated strings and it took me three seconds. Doing this with chars is about to make me lose my mind and I'm running out of time.

Comment: @Victor, `std::sort` takes a begin and end iterator. Pointers qualify as random-access iterators.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to sort an array of `char`s in C++ is to use `std::sort`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
bool anagram(const char *s1, const char *s2) {
    // ...
    std::sort(std::begin(w1), std::end(w1));
    // If you can't use C++11, then use
    // std::sort(w1, w1 + 10); 

    // ...
}
```

If you have to use `qsort` for some weird reason, it expects a function pointer taking two `const void *` parameters that point to the elements to be compared:

```
int compare(const void * e1, const void *e2){
    char c1 = *static_cast<const char *>(e1), c2 = *static_cast<const char *>(e2);
    return c1 - c2;  // <0 if c1 < c2, etc.
}

qsort(w1, 10, sizeof(char), compare);
```

This is slow, error prone, and causes undefined behavior for nontrival types, and is not recommended.

Comment: I originally tried to use the sort function like that, but I kept getting errors and assumed it wasn't possible with a cstring.

[Error] request for member 'begin' in 'w1', which is of non-class type 'char [10]'

Comment: @Victor Use the non-member `std::begin()` as shown above, not `w1.begin()`.

Comment: @TC I tried that also and it's telling me that begin is not a member of std

Comment: @Victor Compile with `-std=c++11`. (If you can't use C++11, then do `std::sort(w1, w1 + 10);`.)

Answer (score 0):

This is your code as you were trying to write it. But as has been pointed out, `qsort` is not the preferred approach.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>


int compare(const void* c1, const void* c2) {
  const char& cc1 = *static_cast<const char*>(c1);
  const char& cc2 = *static_cast<const char*>(c2);
  return cc1 - cc2; }


bool anagram(const char* s1, const char* s2) {
  char w1[10];
  char w2[10];

  for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    w1[i] = s1[i];
    w2[i] = s2[i]; }

  qsort(w1, 10, sizeof(char), compare);
  qsort(w2, 10, sizeof(char), compare);
  return 0 == strncmp(w1, w2, 10); }


int main(int, char* []) {
  std::cout << anagram("abcdefghij", "bcdaghefji") << std::endl;
  std::cout << anagram("abcdefghij", "xxxxxxxxxx") << std::endl;
  return 0; }
```

Comment: I have tried to use the std::sort, but I cannot get it to work properly. I'll post my entire code back at the top.

Comment: Your indentation style is highly peculiar! Do your colleagues not complain?

Comment: You should not be laying out white space manually. My .astylerc is --indent=spaces=2
--indent-switches
--break-blocks
--pad-oper
--pad-header
--unpad-paren
--delete-empty-lines
--align-pointer=type
--add-brackets
--convert-tabs
--remove-comment-prefix
--max-code-length=72
-A12

Comment: Nobody complains because I follow whatever coding conventions are in place for the code I am working on. But when I get to choose I prefer a layout that borrows heavily from lisp.